# UNION / GROUP BY - Prevent NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have three MySQL tables containing weather observations. Now I'm trying to query data out of all these tables grouped by hour. The tables look like:

```
TABLE 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
station     time        temperature     pressure        humidity
--------------------------------------------------------------------
10637       1520512345  22.9            NULL            NULL

TABLE 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
station     time        temperature     pressure        humidity
-------------------------------------------------------------------
10637       1520512345  NULL            1016            NULL

TABLE 3
-------------------------------------------------------------------
station     time        temperature     pressure        humidity
-------------------------------------------------------------------
10637       1520512345  NULL            NULL            76
```

Currently, I use `UNION` along with `GROUP BY` to query an hourly aggregation:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT `time`,`temperature`,`pressure`,`humidity`
       FROM `table_1`
       WHERE `station` = 10637
      ) UNION
      (SELECT `time`,`temperature`,`pressure`,`humidity`
       FROM `table_2`
       WHERE `station` = 10637
      ) UNION
      (SELECT `time`,`temperature`,`pressure`,`humidity`
       FROM `table_3`
       WHERE `station` = 10637
      )
     ) AS `hourly`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`), '%Y %m %d %H')
ORDER BY `time`
```

The query works. It takes one of the available rows for each hour. But as the example shows, some tables contain data that is not available in the others. That causes many unnecessary NULL values in the output. How do I need to change the query so the output contains an aggregation of all data that's `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Why do you have three different tables? Consider one common table!

Comment: The tables are more complex than my post suggested. There are some columns which are only available in a particular table. Also, I have an index for station, time columns. As I want to keep that high degree of redundancy (quality assurance) I decided to use different tables for each of my sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `select *` with `group by`.  It is an anti-pattern and not supported by other databases under most circumstances.  Take the challenge.  Figure out how to combine the results.

In this case, simple aggregation functions work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`), '%Y %m %d %H') as yyyymmddhh,
       AVG(temperature) as temperature,
       AVG(pressure) as pressure,
       AVG(humidity) as humidity
FROM ((SELECT time, temperature, pressure, humidity
       FROM `table_1`
       WHERE `station` = 10637
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT time, temperature, pressure, humidity
       FROM `table_2`
       WHERE `station` = 10637
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT time, temperature, pressure, humidity
       FROM `table_3`
       WHERE `station` = 10637
      )
     ) hourly
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`), '%Y %m %d %H')
ORDER BY yyyymmddhh
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment...

I'm curious as to why you can't store all the data in one table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
station     time        temperature     pressure        humidity
--------------------------------------------------------------------
10637       1520512345  22.9            1016            76
```

Anyway, you might consider an amended schema as follows:

```
station*  time*      metric*       value
-----------------------------------------
10637     1520512345 temperature     22.9            
10637     1520512345 pressure      1016.0            
10637     1520512345 humidity        76.0

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```